# Replace part of string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like the following

```
username=user321@user.com&password=somepassword&grant_type=password
```

I want to replace the value of password i.e. somepassword with *****.

I tried converting to list etc, but that is not well done. Is there a better way to do this in c#

Comment: Study regular expressions. Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that's what i am looking for, regEx has been my weakenss

Comment: Go through some tutorials. Like this one https://regexone.com

Comment: The suggested duplicate question asks a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, which only works if it's a valid query string (you may need that):

```
string line = "username=user321@user.com&password=somepassword&grant_type=password";
var parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(line);
parameters.Set("password", new string('*', parameters["password"].Length));
// Or if you want a fixed amount of asterisks:
// parameters.Set("password", "********");
string fixedLine = parameters.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(line);
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fixedLine));
```

Output:

```
username=user321@user.com&password=somepassword&grant_type=password
username=user321@user.com&password=************&grant_type=password
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 string result = Regex.Replace("username=user321@user.com&grant_type=password&password=somepassword", @"(password=)[^\n]*", "$1********");
```

**[`DEMO`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aKiZ1w)**

Comment: So basically you are forcing the user to first change the order of the parameters for this to work, because it will remove everything from "password" to the end... Not an acceptable solution for me.
I would rather use `Regex.Replace("username=user321@user.com&password=someprd&grant_type=password", @"(&password=)[^\n]*&", "$1********&")` (added 2 `&` to make sure we are matching the correct parameter).